# matplotlib-cpp connecting first and last point in the data set

Tags: c++, windows, matplotlib, plot

I was able to link matplotlib-cpp to visual studio. When I set the data and plot it everything works fine except first point and last point gets connected. I know that the first point and last point is not the same. My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include "matplotlibcpp.h" 

namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;

    fp1 = fopen("data1.tmp", "r"); 
    int num = 139;
    std::vector<double> xval(num + 1), yval(num + 1);

    i = 0;
    while (i < num)
    {
        fscanf(fp1, "%lf \t %lf\n", &xval[i], &yval[i]);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp1);

    plt::figure_size(1200, 780);
    plt::plot(xval,y1val,"r--");
    plt::show();
}
```

My list of data

```
0.000000     0.000000
0.005000     0.005000
0.010000     0.010000
0.015000     0.014999
0.020000     0.019999
0.025000     0.024997
0.030000     0.029996
0.035000     0.034993
0.040000     0.039989
0.045000     0.044985
0.050000     0.049979
0.055000     0.054972
0.060000     0.059964
0.065000     0.064954
0.070000     0.069943
0.075000     0.074930
0.080000     0.079915
0.085000     0.084898
0.090000     0.089879
0.095000     0.094857
0.100000     0.099833
0.105000     0.104807
0.110000     0.109778
0.115000     0.114747
0.120000     0.119712
0.125000     0.124675
0.130000     0.129634
0.135000     0.134590
0.140000     0.139543
0.145000     0.144492
0.150000     0.149438
0.155000     0.154380
0.160000     0.159318
0.165000     0.164252
0.170000     0.169182
0.175000     0.174108
0.180000     0.179030
0.185000     0.183947
0.190000     0.188859
0.195000     0.193767
0.200000     0.198669
0.205000     0.203567
0.210000     0.208460
0.215000     0.213347
0.220000     0.218230
0.225000     0.223106
0.230000     0.227978
0.235000     0.232843
0.240000     0.237703
0.245000     0.242556
0.250000     0.247404
0.255000     0.252245
0.260000     0.257081
0.265000     0.261909
0.270000     0.266731
0.275000     0.271547
0.280000     0.276356
0.285000     0.281157
0.290000     0.285952
0.295000     0.290740
0.300000     0.295520
0.305000     0.300293
0.310000     0.305059
0.315000     0.309816
0.320000     0.314567
0.325000     0.319309
0.330000     0.324043
0.335000     0.328769
0.340000     0.333487
0.345000     0.338197
0.350000     0.342898
0.355000     0.347590
0.360000     0.352274
0.365000     0.356949
0.370000     0.361615
0.375000     0.366273
0.380000     0.370920
0.385000     0.375559
0.390000     0.380188
0.395000     0.384808
0.400000     0.389418
0.405000     0.394019
0.410000     0.398609
0.415000     0.403190
0.420000     0.407760
0.425000     0.412321
0.430000     0.416871
0.435000     0.421410
0.440000     0.425939
0.445000     0.430458
0.450000     0.434966
0.455000     0.439462
0.460000     0.443948
0.465000     0.448423
0.470000     0.452886
0.475000     0.457338
0.480000     0.461779
0.485000     0.466208
0.490000     0.470626
0.495000     0.475032
0.500000     0.479426
0.505000     0.483807
0.510000     0.488177
0.515000     0.492535
0.520000     0.496880
0.525000     0.501213
0.530000     0.505533
0.535000     0.509841
0.540000     0.514136
0.545000     0.518418
0.550000     0.522687
0.555000     0.526943
0.560000     0.531186
0.565000     0.535416
0.570000     0.539632
0.575000     0.543835
0.580000     0.548024
0.585000     0.552199
0.590000     0.556361
0.595000     0.560509
0.600000     0.564642
0.605000     0.568762
0.610000     0.572867
0.615000     0.576959
0.620000     0.581035
0.625000     0.585097
0.630000     0.589145
0.635000     0.593178
0.640000     0.597195
0.645000     0.601198
0.650000     0.605186
0.655000     0.609159
0.660000     0.613117
0.665000     0.617059
0.670000     0.620986
0.675000     0.624897
0.680000     0.628793
0.685000     0.632673
0.690000     0.636537
0.695000     0.640385
0.700000     0.644218
```

and here is the result

[image: graph]

How do I remove that annoying line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines:

```cpp
int num = 139;
std::vector<double> xval(num + 1), yval(num + 1);
```

create vectors `xval` and `yval` of 140 `double` elements initialized to `0`.

You only load 139 points from your dataset and the first point in the dataset  is `(0,0)`; so your first (0-th) and last (139-th) points are indeed equal. You may try:

```cpp
int num = 139;
std::vector<double> xval(num), yval(num);
```